# Is there a performance difference between SVG attributes and styles?

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, d3.js, cross-browser

I'm working with large SVG particle animation that involve lots of little elements. Sometimes up to 1000. Browsers seem to struggle when I animate that many elements, so I'm looking for ways to optimize the code for better, smoother performance (especially Firefix).

My main question is whether there is any difference between, for example, setting an element's `stroke` property as an attribute, or as as style:

```
<circle r="0.15" cx="84" cy="782" stroke-width="6" stroke="transparent" style="fill: #ffffff;"></circle>
```

vs

```
<circle r="0.15" cx="84" cy="782" stroke-width="6" stroke="transparent" style="stroke:transparent; stroke-width:6; fill: #ffffff;"></circle>
```

I'm using D3.js to add a bunch of these and make them move around... and 1000 appears to be roughly the limit before things get clunky in Chrome. Firefox is much worse.

If you have any other performance suggestions they're also welcome.

**Update**
By request:

Here is how I create the nodes:

```
var makeNode = function(coeficient, x, y) {
    coeficient = coeficient || 1;
    return {
        radius: (Math.random() * coeficient ).toFixed(2), 
        cx: function() { return x || Math.round(Math.random()*width) }, 
        cy: function() { return y || Math.round(Math.random()*height) }
    }
};

var nodes1 = d3.range(300).map( function(){ return makeNode(1.9); } );
var nodes2 = d3.range(700).map( function(){ return makeNode(.6); } );
// var nodes2 = [];

var svg = d3.select('#sky_svg');
var group1 = svg.append('g').attr("class", "group1");
var group2 = svg.append('g').attr("class", "group2");

var addNodes = function(group, nodes) {
    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
        var node = nodes[i];
        var circle = group.append('circle');
        circle
            .attr("r", node.radius )
            .attr("cx", node.cx )
            .attr("cy", node.cy )
            .attr("stroke-width", 8 )
            .attr("stroke", "transparent")
            .style("fill", "#FFFFFF");
    }
}

addNodes( group1, nodes1 );
addNodes( group2, nodes2 );
```

And this his how I'm animating them:

```
function orbit( target, ease, duration ) {

  /* Other easing options here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_ease */
ease = ease || 'linear';
duration = duration || 40000;

  target
    .transition()
    .duration( duration )
    .ease( ease )
    .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
    .each('end', function(){ orbit( group1, false ); } );

  function rotTween() {
      var i = d3.interpolate(0, 360);
      return function(t) {
          return "rotate(" + i(t) + ","+width/2+","+height/2+")";
      };
  }

}

orbit( group1, 'sin-in', orbitSpeed );
orbit( group2, 'sin-in', orbitSpeed*2.5 );
```

I'm not especially married to this implementation. My original design used a force layout but Firefox struggled *really* hard to even load it and then it ran terribly so I refactored the code to use a simple rotation (which almost works smoothly in FF).

Comment: This is pretty much guaranteed to be implementation-specific, so as with all performance questions, you must **measure it.**

Comment: This looks very HTML'ish. How do you actually create those circles using JS / D3?

Comment: @user13500 D3 can either change element attributes or change inline styles, other than that the functions are pretty much the same.

Comment: @ SDP It's *possible* that inline styles would be slightly more efficient in a force-layout tick function since they automatically over-ride all stylesheet styles, so the browser wouldn't have to scan through the cascade to determine the active style, but as @MattBall says, you'd really have to test to see if there's a difference.  However, it *could* be reversed if using a transition, because `transition.style()` uses `getComputedStyle` to access the initial value, which would be slower than `getAttribute` (although that would only delay the start of the transition, not the animation).

Comment: @AmeliaBR: Yes, but would really like to see some code to better assess possible culprits. At least some more context. I like that Q is to the point, but never the less ... Eramfh! I'm probably better a candidate for bed right now.,

Comment: @user13500  On second thought, you're right.  The code that @SDP would use would be the same, but the source code implementation could be relevant: [`selection.attr` source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/c247e1626118de41b3d40e2a711354f76e004343/src/selection/attr.js) vs. [`selection.style` source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/c247e1626118de41b3d40e2a711354f76e004343/src/selection/style.js). (Both functions can accept a property name as a getter, name and value as a setter, or a dictionary of name-value pairs.)  Testing for namespaces might slow down `.attr()`. a bit.

Comment: I've update the Q with the requested code.

Answer (score -1):

circles have the `baseVal` for cx,cy,r. It has been suggested that accessing these attributes, via `baseVal`. is more effecient tnan using `setAttribute` or `attr` (in d3).
e.g.

```
myCircle.cx.baseVal.value=myCx
myCircle.cy.baseVal.value=myCy
myCircle.r.baseVal.value=myR
```